# Custom Checkstyle Rule - Unable to instantiate 'TestName' class

Tags: java, maven, gradle, jar, checkstyle

I am trying to add a custom checkstyle rule for test methods. To implement the custom checkstyle rule I followed some guides until I found this [guide](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/custom-developed-checkstyle.html) from Maven which got me the closest to success. Just as it asks, I made my own Maven project with the custom rule and imported it into my other project. So the .jar with my checkstyle rule is there and it is a dependency. My project runs on gradle.

Yet whenever I try to run checkstyle (through gradle for my tests) I get the following stacktrace:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':checkstyleTest'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:207)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:263)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:205)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:186)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:409)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:399)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:242)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:150)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:94)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:356)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: : Unable to create Root Module: config {/Users/amarmesic/Documents/TUDelft/SP/aatom-testing-framework/AATOM/Simulator/config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml}, classpath {/Users/amarmesic/Documents/TUDelft/SP/aatom-testing-framework/AATOM/Simulator/build/classes/java/test:/Users/amarmesic/Documents/TUDelft/SP/aatom-testing-framework/AATOM/Simulator/build/resources/test:/Users/amarmesic/Documents/TUDelft/SP/aatom-testing-framework/AATOM/Simulator/build/classes/java/main:/Users/amarmesic/Documents/TUDelft/SP/aatom-testing-framework/AATOM/Simulator/build/resources/main:/Users/amarmesic/.m2/repository/nl/tudelft/custom-checkstyle/1.0/custom-checkstyle-1.0.jar:/Users/amarmesic/.m2/repository/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/8.36/checkstyle-8.36.jar:/Users/amarmesic/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/29.0-jre/guava-29.0-jre.jar:/Users/amarmesic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jfree/jfreechart/1.5.0/bc7919249bac68c15c433ed51cb798a1bf8cd74e/jfreechart-1.5.0.jar:/Users/amarmesic/.m2/repository/org/reflections/reflections/0.9.12/reflections-0.9.12.jar:/Users/amarmesic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter/5.5.2/f8561a498ec26b24a3a64aebb6b2307fed000a33/junit-jupiter-5.5.2.jar:/Users/amarmesic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mockito/mockito-junit-jupiter/3.1.0/3c181fd8296b86671a8a466b642ba564b1237c13/mockito-junit-jupiter-3.1.0.jar:/Users/amarmesic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.1.0/53137a5fccdccb0d907d409dc68a282aab87c968/mockito-core-3.1.0.jar:/Users/amarmesic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.14.0/3b7b0fcac821f3d167764e9926573cd64f78f9e9/assertj-core-3.14.0.jar:/Users/amarmesic/.m2/repository/checkstyle/checkstyle/5.0/checkstyle-5.0.jar:/Users/amarmesic/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.26.0-GA/javassist-3.26.0-GA.jar:/Users/amarmesic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-params/5.5.2/e0659722923bd9fdfa08602e2da22bd5a9d354e8/junit-jupiter-params-5.5.2.jar:/Users/amarmesic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api/5.5.2/6393db7e4c0265152d8fc4ff146633d1a7d36c47/junit-jupiter-api-5.5.2.jar:/Users/amarmesic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.9.10/211a2b4d3df1eeef2a6cacf78d74a1f725e7a840/byte-buddy-1.9.10.jar:/Users/amarmesic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy-agent/1.9.10/9674aba5ee793e54b864952b001166848da0f26b/byte-buddy-agent-1.9.10.jar:/Users/amarmesic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.objenesis/objenesis/2.6/639033469776fd37c08358c6b92a4761feb2af4b/objenesis-2.6.jar:/Users/amarmesic/.m2/repository/info/picocli/picocli/4.5.1/picocli-4.5.1.jar:/Users/amarmesic/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/Users/amarmesic/.m2/repository/org/antlr/antlr4-runtime/4.8-1/antlr4-runtime-4.8-1.jar:/Users/amarmesic/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.9.4/commons-beanutils-1.9.4.jar:/Users/amarmesic/.m2/repository/net/sf/saxon/Saxon-HE/9.9.1-7/Saxon-HE-9.9.1-7.jar:/Users/amarmesic/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils-core/1.7.0/commons-beanutils-core-1.7.0.jar:/Users/amarmesic/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.0/commons-cli-1.0.jar:/Users/amarmesic/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/Users/amarmesic/.m2/repository/com/google/collections/google-collections/0.9/google-collections-0.9.jar:/Users/amarmesic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.junit.platform/junit-platform-commons/1.5.2/9703df63b65d415b2a027d43ce908c625b3aedce/junit-platform-commons-1.5.2.jar:/Users/amarmesic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apiguardian/apiguardian-api/1.1.0/fc9dff4bb36d627bdc553de77e1f17efd790876c/apiguardian-api-1.1.0.jar:/Users/amarmesic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.opentest4j/opentest4j/1.2.0/28c11eb91f9b6d8e200631d46e20a7f407f2a046/opentest4j-1.2.0.jar:/Users/amarmesic/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/failureaccess/1.0.1/failureaccess-1.0.1.jar:/Users/amarmesic/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/listenablefuture/9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava/listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava.jar:/Users/amarmesic/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/3.0.2/jsr305-3.0.2.jar:/Users/amarmesic/.m2/repository/org/checkerframework/checker-qual/2.11.1/checker-qual-2.11.1.jar:/Users/amarmesic/.m2/repository/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.3.4/error_prone_annotations-2.3.4.jar:/Users/amarmesic/.m2/repository/com/google/j2objc/j2objc-annotations/1.3/j2objc-annotations-1.3.jar:/Users/amarmesic/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.2/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/Users/amarmesic/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/1.0/commons-lang-1.0.jar:/Users/amarmesic/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.7/junit-3.7.jar}.
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.ant.CheckstyleAntTask.createRootModule(CheckstyleAntTask.java:424)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.ant.CheckstyleAntTask.realExecute(CheckstyleAntTask.java:320)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.ant.CheckstyleAntTask.execute(CheckstyleAntTask.java:302)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.BasicAntBuilder.nodeCompleted(BasicAntBuilder.java:80)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor745.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:484)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:196)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.invokeMethod(AbstractDynamicObject.java:163)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.antbuilder.AntBuilderDelegate.nodeCompleted(AntBuilderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.internal.CheckstyleInvoker$_invoke_closure1.doCall(CheckstyleInvoker.groovy:58)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.gradle.util.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:71)
    at org.gradle.util.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.antbuilder.DefaultIsolatedAntBuilder$2.execute(DefaultIsolatedAntBuilder.java:154)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.antbuilder.DefaultIsolatedAntBuilder$2.execute(DefaultIsolatedAntBuilder.java:136)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.antbuilder.ClassPathToClassLoaderCache.withCachedClassLoader(ClassPathToClassLoaderCache.java:135)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.antbuilder.DefaultIsolatedAntBuilder.execute(DefaultIsolatedAntBuilder.java:130)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.IsolatedAntBuilder$execute$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.internal.CheckstyleInvoker.invoke(CheckstyleInvoker.groovy:51)
    at org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.Checkstyle.run(Checkstyle.java:151)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:726)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:693)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:569)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:395)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:387)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:242)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:150)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:84)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:554)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:537)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$300(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:108)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:278)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:267)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$1(ExecuteStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:67)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:159)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:72)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:85)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:94)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:79)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:28)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:194)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:186)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:409)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:399)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:242)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:150)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:94)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:356)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.CheckstyleException: cannot initialize module TreeWalker - cannot initialize module TestName - Unable to instantiate 'TestName' class, it is also not possible to instantiate it as .TestName, TestNameCheck, .TestNameCheck. Please recheck that class name is specified as canonical name or read how to configure short name usage https://checkstyle.org/config.html#Packages. Please also recheck that provided ClassLoader to Checker is configured correctly.
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Checker.setupChild(Checker.java:482)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.AutomaticBean.configure(AutomaticBean.java:201)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.ant.CheckstyleAntTask.createRootModule(CheckstyleAntTask.java:421)
    ... 122 more
Caused by: com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.CheckstyleException: cannot initialize module TestName - Unable to instantiate 'TestName' class, it is also not possible to instantiate it as .TestName, TestNameCheck, .TestNameCheck. Please recheck that class name is specified as canonical name or read how to configure short name usage https://checkstyle.org/config.html#Packages. Please also recheck that provided ClassLoader to Checker is configured correctly.
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.TreeWalker.setupChild(TreeWalker.java:125)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.AutomaticBean.configure(AutomaticBean.java:201)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Checker.setupChild(Checker.java:477)
    ... 124 more
Caused by: com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.CheckstyleException: Unable to instantiate 'TestName' class, it is also not possible to instantiate it as .TestName, TestNameCheck, .TestNameCheck. Please recheck that class name is specified as canonical name or read how to configure short name usage https://checkstyle.org/config.html#Packages. Please also recheck that provided ClassLoader to Checker is configured correctly.
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.PackageObjectFactory.createModule(PackageObjectFactory.java:215)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.TreeWalker.setupChild(TreeWalker.java:116)
    ... 126 more
```

I built my custom checker similar to the standard checkstyle methodNameCheck Class. Here's my custom checker for test names:

```
import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.DetailAST;
import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.TokenTypes;
import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.naming.AbstractAccessControlNameCheck;
import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.utils.AnnotationUtil;

public class TestNameCheck extends AbstractAccessControlNameCheck {

    public static final String CATCH_MSG = "Test name does not follow naming conventions";
    private static final String TEST = "Test";
    private static final String CANONICAL_TEST = "org.junit.jupiter.api." + TEST;
    private static final String PARAM_TEST = "ParameterizedTest";
    private static final String CANONICAL_PARAM_TEST = "org.junit.jupiter.params." + PARAM_TEST;

    /**
     * Creates a new {@code TestNameCheck} instance.
     */
    public TestNameCheck() {
        super("^[a-z].*Test$");
    }


    @Override
    public int[] getDefaultTokens() {
        return getRequiredTokens();
    }

    @Override
    public int[] getAcceptableTokens() {
        return getRequiredTokens();
    }

    @Override
    public int[] getRequiredTokens() {
        return new int[] {TokenTypes.METHOD_DEF, };
    }


    @Override
    public void visitToken(DetailAST ast) {
        if (AnnotationUtil.containsAnnotation(ast, TEST)
                || AnnotationUtil.containsAnnotation(ast, CANONICAL_TEST)
                || AnnotationUtil.containsAnnotation(ast, PARAM_TEST)
                || AnnotationUtil.containsAnnotation(ast, CANONICAL_PARAM_TEST)) {
            // Will check the name against the format.
            super.visitToken(ast);
        }
    }



}
```

I cannot figure out why it is unable instantiate the class when the constructor is the same as for many other *Check class.

Comment: Have you tried to use the fully qualified name of your check?

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

Make sure the dependency with you custom check is added to the plugin, not necessarily to the project.

### Details

I had the same issue (using maven) and I was indeed using the fully qualified name as suggested by Nick Mancuso in the comments. The solution came from that maven guide you posted in your question, specifically this section: [Configure the checkstyle plugin to use your custom checks](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/custom-developed-checkstyle.html#configure-the-checkstyle-plugin-to-use-your-custom-checks). I was following the [writing checks](https://checkstyle.org/writingchecks.html) guide on the Checkstyle site which shows [here](https://checkstyle.org/writingchecks.html#Integrating_Checks) how to run the checks from the command line.

```
java -classpath mycompanychecks.jar:checkstyle-${projectVersion}-all.jar \
              com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Main -c config.xml myproject
```

If you look closely, the jar with the custom check is passed to the classpath of the checkstyle execution, which on maven is done by adding the dependency to the plugin as mentioned above.

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>mycompany-checkstyle-checks</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Once I added that dependency there (rather than as a regular project dependency) it worked.

### Gradle

Unfortunately I don't use Gradle at all, but I do see that Gradle's checkstyle plugin has a [dependecy management](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/checkstyle_plugin.html#sec:checkstyle_dependency_management) section, which according to the documentation allows to configure `The Checkstyle libraries to use`, so that's likely the place where the library with your custom checks should go.